# Line plot using matplotlib for a dataframe of 200 columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, dataframe

I am struggling to plot line graph for a data Frame I have . The data frame consist of 200 column and approximately 4900 rows.
It head of my dataframe looks as follows,

```
Geneid  pool16.1    pool18.13   pool14.11   pool15.6    pool15.2    pool17.1    pool14.16   pool14.9    pool15.10   ... pool3.13    pool2.3 pool4.7 pool1.16    pool3.14    pool1.14    pool2.14    pool8.7 pool9.15    pool10.11
0   ABL1.exon1  1073    594 901 1164    1117    1681    1516    914 1002    

    ... 1471    1086    1032    1600    1023    1203    1465    546 650 947
    1   ABL1.exon2  974 549 738 1006    1057    1463    1463    783 1334    ... 1288    1095    967 1474    881 1134    1326    595 505 912
    2   ABL1.exon3  701 619 471 748 732 1043    1145    531 935 ... 1031    871 702 1206    771 985 1236    301 301 710
    3   ABL1.exon4  555 225 371 586 559 842 830 402 636 ... 831 621 555 887 575 726 936 359 238 556
    4   ABL1.exon5  1063    524 817 1085    1086    1624    1448    843 1368    ... 1523    1234    1185    1883    1025    1387    1655    732 581 882
    5 rows × 199 columns
```

So I wanted to plot a line graph from the above dataFrame, here is what I tried,When a small part of the data frame is used to plot,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.style.use('ggplot')


CDKN2A= All_pools[All_pools.Geneid.str.contains("CDKN2A") == True]

CDKN2A.plot.line(figsize=(15,10),x='Geneid',y='value')
```

Which gives plot which looks like this,

[image]

Where I have no information about the first column on x axis and and the plot no informative. I aiming to plot something which looks like this,

[image]

Still the plot look so screwed no much informative...Any suggestions to make it look better would be great..

Comment: Wow! Hou did you manage to produce such a figure with that `.plot()` call? Well I don't have the data so I can't tell what's going on but it looks really weird to me. Anyway "Any suggestions to make it look better" is too broad. I am still under the impression that you don't like your data so maybe get nicer data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see dates in the x axis you need a column with dates in your dataframe.

If you want to see several lines you need to plot several columns.

If you want to see an actual, distinct line, you need to plot less rows or more autocorrelated data or both.

You already have information about the first column on x axis: the column name and some values labelled, as usual.

Comment: So for those above line plots one need a dataframe with dates in the first column ?

Comment: @ user1017373 No, for plots that have dates in the x axis you need dates in some column (or array or list orr... well, somewhere).

Comment: No my dataframe is as I have showed in my post , and my question is I wanted  line plot where I could see each of my rows as separate as the example plot I have shown (the plot with dates).

Comment: @user1017373 I expanded my answer but at this point I am just guessing what you want. I am beginning to think you just don't like your data. I don't know how to help with that.

Comment: Plotting less rows helped me but still the plot look so screwed and ..and congested ...

Comment: Could please take a look into the actual question..I have taken a small part of the whole DataFrame and so I have the above plot..Still the plot doesn't look good..Also I mean median plotted as dotted lines for each column..I dont how to attain that...